# how to clear a buffer after use?

Tags: java

I am using  a BufferedReader. I just wanna know how to clear the BufferedReader after every line is read values from keyboard. I am using like

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String male = br.readLine();
```

please help me out.

Comment: Where is the string buffer? I guess we need some code...

Comment: i mean to say buffer reader to read lines.if say there are 100 lines .at some point it may through error .so how to clear this buffer .

Comment: Are you actually asking 'how to properly read an InputStream' without it throwing Exceptions?

Comment: Please update your answer (and title) to clarify. It seems that people are answering the wrong question.

Comment: Are you using an instance of StringBuffer or are you referring to a buffered stream?

Comment: no , i am using an instance of stringBuffer

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'clear?' If it's reading from the console there won't be anything in it after the newline corresponding to the ENTER key. So nothing to clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not really any reason to "clear" the String "buffer".  If you are worried about memory use, the String will automatically be garbage collected by the JVM when it is no longer used.

However,

```
str = null;
```

will effectively remove the reference to the String.  Strings are immutable, so you can't modify the "buffer" and clear it, the best you can do is remove the reference to it and then have it garbage collected.

EDIT

To answer the question about BufferedReaders...

There is no need and no way to "clear" a BufferedReader.  If you encounter an error, you can simply call readLine() again, and nothing you read before should have any effect.  If you were reading from file and got an exception, you should check if you are at the end of the file, but because you are reading from keyboard, I would advise simply calling readLine() again.

Comment: thank u , but is there any method or function to clear the BUFFER .

Answer (score 5):

It makes no sense to clear the buffer.

If it were an output buffer e.g. BufferedWriter, then you could flush the buffer to make sure that all buffered content has been written before closing the buffer.
In this case you can just close the buffer, after br.readLine() returns null, which means that there is no more input to be read.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that because this BufferedReader is reading in from keyboard, you should never get null from br.readLine().

Comment: @Zach, if System.in stream is ended, then null will be returned.